# Reading Quran from the mus'haf but not facing the qiblah?

Tags: quran, qiblah, mushaf

I just found out that we have to face the qiblah when reading Quran from the mus'haf.

I usually read from the mus'haf in my bed before sleeping which is facing opposite the qiblah.

Does reading Quran from the mus'haf another direction than the qiblah have an effect on the deeds or validity?

Comment: "we have to" expresses that something is ordered, while in fact there's no such order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facing the qiblah is not obligatory in other than salah and what comes under its ruling. Facing the qiblah while reciting the Quran would be mustahab but not required, and there is no effect on its validity.

https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/11761/